# Is there any single sql statement for doing Bulk Update?

Tags: mysql, sql

I just had one sql doubt, actually I need to use update query many times for each color value... Its becoming tough to check condition each time for each color..

**Is there any single sql statement for doing below Bulk 'update'? Please tell me..**

```
update `myTable` set `COLOR`='white'  WHERE `CATEGORY` = 'Dress' and `NAME` like '%white%'
update `myTable` set `COLOR`='red'  WHERE `CATEGORY` = 'Dress' and `NAME` like '%red%'
update `myTable` set `COLOR`='blue'  WHERE `CATEGORY` = 'Dress' and `NAME` like '%blue%'
update `myTable` set `COLOR`='pink'  WHERE `CATEGORY` = 'Dress' and `NAME` like '%pink%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE`

```
Update  myTable
SET     COLOR = CASE 
                     WHEN  CATEGORY = 'white' AND NAME like '%white%' THEN 'white'
                     WHEN  CATEGORY = 'red' AND NAME like '%red%' THEN 'red'
                     WHEN  CATEGORY = 'blue' AND NAME like '%blue%' THEN 'blue'
                     WHEN  CATEGORY = 'pink' AND NAME like '%pink%' THEN 'pink'
                     ELSE  value 
                END
WHERE   CATEGORY  IN ('white','red','blue','pink')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update `myTable` set `COLOR`=CASE WHEN NAME LIKE '%white%' THEN 'white'  
WHEN NAME LIKE '%red%' THEN 'red'
...
END /*ends the CASE statement*/
WHERE `CATEGORY` = 'Dress' and 
(
`NAME` like '%white%' OR
`NAME` like '%red%' OR
...
)
```

Actually, since queries with `LIKE '%whatever'` have to do a full table scan anyway, you can simply do it like this:

```
update `myTable` set `COLOR`=CASE WHEN NAME LIKE '%white%' THEN 'white'  
WHEN NAME LIKE '%red%' THEN 'red'
...
ELSE `COLOR`
END /*ends the CASE statement*/
WHERE `CATEGORY` = 'Dress'
```

Easier written, but you also update every row (sometimes with the value it had before, if MySQL isn't smart enough to not update then).